# exporting constructors into the FreeMarker data model

Tags: java, freemarker

Is there any way to export a *specific* class constructor into the FreeMarker data model?

[`ObjectConstructor`](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/utility/ObjectConstructor.html) provides the power to access *any* accessible constructor:

Java:

```
myDataModel.put("objectConstructor", new ObjectConstructor());
```

Template:

```
<#assign aList = objectConstructor("java.util.ArrayList", 100)>
```

But I don't want to do that; if I have a class `Foo` with two constructors `Foo(int x)` and `Foo(String name, int x)`, I want to somehow export an object into the data model as `Foo` so I can do this in a template:

```
<#assign myfoo1 = Foo(1) >
<#assign myfoo2 = Foo("Buffalo Bill", 2) >
```

I can do this manually with [`TemplateMethodModelEx`](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/TemplateMethodModelEx.html) but it requires me to implement `exec(List arguments)` and figure out how to pull the arguments out and push them into my `Foo` class constructor.

What I would like is a `ClassConstructor` object that takes a `Class<T>` argument of the class in question, and implements `TemplateMethodModelEx` and automatically does the casting, the same way that FreeMarker automatically handles Java object method calls, and I could do this in Java:

```
myDataModel.put("Foo", new ClassConstructor(Foo.class));
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling Java methods and constructors from FTL is the business of `BeansWrapper`, which is also the superclass of `DefaultObjectWrapper` and of most custom `ObjectWrapper`-s you find out there. So, `ObjectWrapper.newInstance(Class clazz, List/*<TemplateModel>*/ arguments)` can do the tricky part for you. The others are some trivial plumbing (and I went a bit fancy here with getting the `ObjectWrapper` - that's optional):

```
package freemarker.adhoc;

import java.util.List;

import freemarker.core.Environment;
import freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper;
import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.ObjectWrapper;
import freemarker.template.TemplateMethodModelEx;
import freemarker.template.TemplateModelException;

/**
 * Creates an FTL method that calls the constructor of the given class. Supports overloading and varargs. 
 */
public class ConstructorTemplateModel implements TemplateMethodModelEx {

    private final Class constructorClass;
    private final BeansWrapper objectWrapper;

    /**
     * @param objectWrapper
     *            The same {@link ObjectWrapper} used in the {@link Configuration}, or {@code null} if we should
     *            find the current {@link ObjectWrapper} for each constructor call (slower).
     */
    public ConstructorTemplateModel(Class<?> constructorClass, BeansWrapper objectWrapper) {
        this.constructorClass = constructorClass;
        this.objectWrapper = objectWrapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Object exec(List/*<TemplateModel>*/ arguments) throws TemplateModelException {
        BeansWrapper objectWrapper = this.objectWrapper;
        if (objectWrapper == null) {
            objectWrapper = getCurrentBeansWrapper();
        }

        return objectWrapper.newInstance(constructorClass, arguments);
    }

    private BeansWrapper getCurrentBeansWrapper() {
        Environment env = Environment.getCurrentEnvironment();
        if (env == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No ongoing template processing");
        }

        ObjectWrapper objectWrapper = env.getObjectWrapper();
        if (!(objectWrapper instanceof BeansWrapper)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The object wrapper must be a BeansWrapper. Object wrapper class: "
                    + objectWrapper.getClass().getName());
        }

        return (BeansWrapper) objectWrapper;
    }

}
```

Comment: ... a little confused here: why not just create a static instance of `DefaultObjectWrapper` and use it to call `newInstance()` ? I am confused  why there would be anything stateful required to do this; given the `List` of arguments and the `class` in question, isn't that enough to unambiguously call constructors?

Comment: When you wrap an object with an `ObjectWrapper` (in this case that object is the constructor), the way you will see that object from the templates, and the way you will see the objects you reach through that object, and so on recursively, will depend on that same inital `ObjectWrapper`. So if in your `Configutation` you have a custom `ObjectWrapper`, or even just a `DefaultObjectWrapper` that uses different settings than the default, then certainly you want that to be used everywhere.